# Use jQuery ajax from nodeJS interpreter

Tags: jquery, node.js, same-origin-policy

I'm running a development server on `localhost:8080` and now working on a terminal. I installed `nodejs` with the following commands:

```
$ brew install node
$ brew install jquery
```

Now I run the `node` interpreter:

```
$ node
> var $ = require("jquery");
```

I defined a function to print out to the console whatever it obtains:

```
function getSomething() {
    $.get("http://localhost:8080",
          function(response) {
              console.log(response);
    });
}
```

And so in the interpreter:

```
> getSomething()
undefined <-- this is what I get
```

I think this is due to the same origin policy. How do I get around this? I'm trying to practice my JavaScript and I'd like to work in a terminal instead of a browser console to keep it fast.

Answer (score 2):

1. `getSomething` doens't return anything. So `undefined` is the default return value. this is correct.
2. What part of node's core API do you think does ajax? Is it by any chance `window.XMLHttpRequest`. Does that by any chance not exist?
3. Why would you use jQuery with node? Is it to abstract away cross browser compliance issues? What's that? They don't exist? Then don't use jQuery
4. You probably don't understand that a GET request has to be asynchronous thus can't return anything, it will log a response once it get's back
5. If you want to practice JavaScript then using jQuery won't help you

Seriously though, the way to make HTTP requests is easy

`$ npm install request`

```
var request = require("request");

function makeRequest(callback) {
  request("http://localhost:8080", callback);
}

makeRequest(function (err, res, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```